# How to enable post service call from client using spring rest security x509 authentication

Tags: java, security, spring-boot

I have tried to enable post service call from REST client using spring rest security x509 authentication, but it throws below exception

```
"exception": "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException",
"message": "403 null"
```

### I have referred the below example

https://github.com/chathurangat/spring-rest-security-x509-authentication

Any one can help to resolve the issue, thanks in advance

### Client Side Request Program

```
// configuring the keyStore and trustStore for the client application
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "src/main/resources/clientkeystore.p12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "3edc4rfv");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "src/main/resources/clienttruststore.p12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "3edc4rfv");

    RestTemplate template=new RestTemplate();        
    DTO dto=new DTO();
    dto.setName("KMK");
    RequestEntity request=null;
    try {
        request = RequestEntity.post(new URI("https://localhost:8443/logged_info_post")).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(dto);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange(request, String.class);
    return response.getBody();
```

### Server Side Program

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logged_info_post", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public @ResponseBody String helloController_post(@RequestBody DTO dto)
    {
        String loggedUser;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        loggedUser = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        loggedUser = principal.toString();
    }
    return "X.509 authentication done! REST client has been identified as ["+loggedUser+"] " + dto.getName();
}
```

Comment: Share you spring security configuration.

Comment: Server application pom.xml  spring security configuration

                <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: Application.properties server.port = 8443
#keystore details
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/serverkeystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=1qaz2wsx

#truststore details
server.ssl.trust-store=src/main/resources/servertruststore.p12
server.ssl.trust-store-password=1qaz2wsx
server.ssl.client-auth=need

Comment: #I am doubting certificate, which is shared in following link https://github.com/chathurangat/spring-rest-security-x509-authentication/tree/master/keystores

Comment: currently i am using self-signed certificate